# iOS app is Ready for Sale in iTunes Connect but not available in Appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

My app is "ready for sale" in Itunes connect, when i tried with "View on App Store" it says "The item you've requested us not currently available in the US.Store.

[image: Image when opened in iTunes]

Comment: How long since the app's status changed to ready for sale? It generally takes around 24 hours for the app to be available in all territories.

Comment: the app is in Ready for Sale from past 72 hours,

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bizztag/id1042240554?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: Contacting Apple would be the best option.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to do that like any mail id or number to talk apple team help

Comment: [iTunes Connect support](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=contactUs)

Comment: getting same problem.
did you resolved this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

First You have to move to US store and then check for the app.

Comment: Please provide steps how to do this